# Why title is not align to items value using flex.?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Can you please help me Why title is not align to items value using flex. I am using flex box . In all rows we are using “align-self” : “flex-start” . still and header and rows are not align. Kindly help

```
[![export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "space-around",
          alignContent: "flex-start",
        }}
      >
        <span style={{ alignSelf: "flex-start" }}>ooasdasd</span>
        <span style={{ alignSelf: "flex-start" }}>sss</span>
        <span style={{ alignSelf: "flex-start" }}>asasda</span>
      </div>

      <li
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "space-around",
          alignContent: "flex-start",
          padding: 0,
          margin: 0,
        }}
      >
        <span style={{ alignSelf: "flex-start" }}>kaveennnn</span>
        <span style={{ alignSelf: "flex-start" }}>jakhdahdsk</span>
        <span style={{ alignSelf: "flex-start" }}>asdasd asdas</span>
      </li>

      <li
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "space-around",
          alignContent: "flex-start",
          padding: 0,
          margin: 0,
        }}
      >
        <span style={{ alignSelf: "flex-start" }}>kaveennnn</span>
        <span style={{ alignSelf: "flex-start" }}>jakhdahdsk</span>
        <span style={{ alignSelf: "flex-start" }}>asdasd asdas</span>
      </li>
    </>
  );

}][1]][1]
```

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/testing-f5htxq?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A3%2C1-47%2C2

[image]

Comment: Please post rendered HTML. I also doubt that the issue is connected to JS or React.

Answer (score 0):

```
<span style={{ alignSelf: "flex-start", flex: 1 }}>kaveennnn</span>
```

try adding flex:1 to the span element and use text align property to align text inside span.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set a `width: 59px` (You can also try `max-width` or `min-width`) to the children and `text-align` to the left, so that they all start at the same point! Also since the child is fixed width, you can allow it to `wrap` or just overflow outside the container!

```
     <span
      style={{
        alignSelf: "flex-start",
        textAlign: "start",
        width: "59px",
      }}
    >
```

[code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/testing-forked-fpmf6y?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A20%2C19)